# Lose leading zeros withe Split array

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to stop split array adding leading zeros?

Issue I have is as follows...

I have a string of barcodes like below
817513015311, 787734332439
I am using split array to break up the line and then use

```
Set UpdateRow = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier Price File").Range("f2:f" & LastRow_MSF).Find(PCodeToChk)
```

to look up PcodetoChk in another sheet

The values in the other sheet do not have leading zeros and would be stored as above...

when I run the split array it adds a 0 to the front and the Lookup is not finding the item ... or is there another way to do the lookup ...

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReverseSearch()
Dim WS_MSF As Worksheet
Dim WS_ADF As Worksheet
Dim WS_RES As Worksheet
Dim TBL_MSF  As ListObject
Dim TBL_ADF  As ListObject
Set WS_MSF = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier Price File")
Set WS_ADF = Sheets("IMPORT - Amazon Data")
Set WS_RES = Sheets("Sheet2")

Set TBL_MSF = WS_MSF.ListObjects("MSPF_Table")
Set TBL_ADF = WS_ADF.ListObjects("IMPORT_Table")


Dim c As Long
Dim LastRow_MSF As Long
Dim LastRow_ADF As Long
Dim EANToChk As String
Dim EAN_Split() As String
Dim PCodeToChk As String

Dim PCode_Split() As String

Dim I As Long
Dim UpdateRow As Range
Dim nextUpdateRow As Long
Dim foundrow As Long
Dim MatchedEAN As String
Dim Supplier As String
Dim Item As String
Dim ItemDesc As String
Dim NettUnitCost As Double
Dim Match As String
Dim Asin As String

'
'Get Last Row of Master Supplier File & Amazon Data File
'
LastRow_MSF = TBL_MSF.Range.Rows(TBL_MSF.Range.Rows.Count).Row
LastRow_ADF = TBL_ADF.Range.Rows(TBL_ADF.Range.Rows.Count).Row

nextUpdateRow = 1
For c = 2 To LastRow_ADF
Asin = WS_ADF.Range("d" & c)
EAN_Split = Split(WS_ADF.Range("a" & c), ",")
PCode_Split = Split(WS_ADF.Range("b" & c), ",")
WS_MSF.Activate

Debug.Print Asin
'
'Check EAN field
'
For I = LBound(EAN_Split()) To UBound(EAN_Split())
Match = ""
EANToChk = EAN_Split(I)


Set UpdateRow = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier Price File").Range("f2:f" & LastRow_MSF).Find(EANToChk)
    
             If Not UpdateRow Is Nothing Then
                    Match = "Match"
                    foundrow = UpdateRow.Row
                    MatchedEAN = WS_MSF.Range("f" & foundrow).Value
                    Supplier = WS_MSF.Range("c" & foundrow).Value
                    Item = WS_MSF.Range("g" & foundrow).Value
                    ItemDesc = WS_MSF.Range("h" & foundrow).Value
                    NettUnitCost = WS_MSF.Range("m" & foundrow).Value
                    nextUpdateRow = nextUpdateRow + 1
                    WS_RES.Range("a" & nextUpdateRow) = MatchedEAN
                    WS_RES.Range("b" & nextUpdateRow) = Supplier
                    WS_RES.Range("c" & nextUpdateRow) = NettUnitCost
                    WS_RES.Range("d" & nextUpdateRow) = Item
                    WS_RES.Range("e" & nextUpdateRow) = ItemDesc
                    WS_RES.Range("f" & nextUpdateRow) = "EAN"
                    If Match = "Match" Then Exit For
              End If
Next I
'
'Check Part code field
'
If Match = "" Then
For I = LBound(PCode_Split()) To UBound(PCode_Split())
PCodeToChk = PCode_Split(I)

Debug.Print PCodeToChk

Set UpdateRow = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier Price File").Range("f2:f" & LastRow_MSF).Find(PCodeToChk)
    
             If Not UpdateRow Is Nothing Then
                    Match = "Match"
                    foundrow = UpdateRow.Row
                    MatchedEAN = WS_MSF.Range("f" & foundrow).Value
                    Supplier = WS_MSF.Range("c" & foundrow).Value
                    Item = WS_MSF.Range("g" & foundrow).Value
                    ItemDesc = WS_MSF.Range("h" & foundrow).Value
                    NettUnitCost = WS_MSF.Range("m" & foundrow).Value
                    nextUpdateRow = nextUpdateRow + 1
                    WS_RES.Range("a" & nextUpdateRow) = MatchedEAN
                    WS_RES.Range("b" & nextUpdateRow) = Supplier
                    WS_RES.Range("c" & nextUpdateRow) = NettUnitCost
                    WS_RES.Range("d" & nextUpdateRow) = Item
                    WS_RES.Range("e" & nextUpdateRow) = ItemDesc
                    WS_RES.Range("f" & nextUpdateRow) = "PartCode"
                    
                    If Match = "Match" Then Exit For
              End If
              If Match = "" Then
              WS_RES.Range("a" & nextUpdateRow) = MatchedEAN
              WS_RES.Range("g" & nextUpdateRow) = Asin
              WS_RES.Range("f" & nextUpdateRow) = "No Match"
              WS_RES.Range("h" & nextUpdateRow) = WS_ADF.Range("a" & c)
              WS_RES.Range("i" & nextUpdateRow) = WS_ADF.Range("b" & c)
              End If
Next I
End If



Next c
End Sub
```

[image: Returned values]
[image: What I am looking up]
I think the space must be the issue?

Comment: `Split` does not add zeros. Furthermore, when you use `Find`, you need to specify several parameters: `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` at the minimum. You're only specifying the first. It would really help if you provided more code than just one line.

Comment: ok thanks will add code... i thought there may have been a simple anwer

Comment: @bigben added code and screenshots

Comment: think you may have pointed me in righr direction - i didn't realise there where additional parameters in the Find... should I just add  Loolkat with XLPArt?

Comment: You should definitely specify the `LookAt` yes. Though from your screenshot it's `EANToChk` that has a leading zero. What is your source data in column A? Also looks like you either `Trim` or split on `", "` to remove the whitespace.

Comment: source is 817513015311, 787734332439... so i think the trim/split on ", " should work!